# как ссылкой отправить запрос в search model?

Tags: php, yii2

с помощью ссылки формируется такой GET `catalog/index?cat_name=Мясные+продукты`

c с помощью формы формируется такой GET `catalog/index?ProductSearchFront%5Bcat_name%5D=Мясные+продукты`

как добиться передачи get запроса формы, но с помощью ссылки??

Comment: как ссылку то генерируете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
echo Url::to(['/catalog/index', 'ProductSearchFront' => ['cat_name' => 'Meat products']]);;

// выведет /catalog/index?ProductSearchFront%5Bcat_name%5D=Meat+products
```